# How to return a Promise of an array in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise

I'm trying to return an array in a form of promise. I first unzipped a file, then parsed the file with csv-parse. I'm saving all returned objects in an array, then return this array

I tried to return without a promise the transpiler didn't complain. But I want to scale it

```
/**
 * Wraps writeFile in a promise.
 * @param content The Base64 content of the file to read.
 * @returns A buffer containing the contents of the file.
 */
protected writeFileAsync(path: string, content: Buffer): Promise<IProblem[]> {
    new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile(path, content,  "base64", (err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }

            resolve(content);
        });
    })
    .then(result => {
        fs.readFile(result, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                Log.error("Error while reading the zip file");
                this.listOfProblems = [];
                return this.listOfProblems;
            }
            let zip: JSZip = new JSZip();
            zip.loadAsync(data)
            .then(contents => {
                Object.keys(contents.files).forEach(filename => {
                    zip.file(filename).async('nodebuffer')
                    .then(content => {
                        let parser: csvParse.Parser = csvParse((data, err) => {
                            if (err) {
                                Log.error("Error while reading the zip file");
                                this.listOfProblems = [];
                                return this.listOfProblems;
                            }
                            let problem: IProblem;

                        }) as csvParse.Parser;
                        fs.createReadStream(content).pipe(parser);
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })
    .catch(() => {
        Log.error("Error while reading the zip file");
        this.listOfProblems = [];
        return this.listOfProblems;
    });
    return this.listOfProblems;
}
```

It's showing error in the last line

Answer (score 0):

You have to return your promise and not the list.

```
return new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
```

Comment: That means I have also to change the method signature to Promise<Buffer> ?

Comment: Yes you need to change it.

Comment: I tried to change it all turned to red with the message: Type 'Promise<void | IProblem[]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Buffer>'.
  Type 'void | IProblem[]' is not assignable to type 'Buffer'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Buffer'

Comment: Okay so the problem is that you are alway returning your list of problems or void if there are no errors.. you should restructure your code so that it rejects with the list of errors and resolves with the content